# How to use cassandra-loader on ubuntu

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-14.04

I want to use cassandra-loader on ubuntu 14.04.
I have cassandra installed on my machine along with other prerequisites require for loader.

I am following this link for the same;
https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

I downloaded the cassandra-loader tool but when trying to run any cassandra-loader command it prompts cassandra-loader command not found.

Kindly guide if I am missing anything or need to install other prerequisite as well.

Answer (score 0):

in the README it says:

> To run cassandra-loader, simply run the cassandra-loader executable (e.g., located at `build/cassandra-loader`)

so everywhere where you see the `cassandra-loader` alone, or just copy `build/cassandra-loader` somewhere in your `PATH` and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Done. Just needed to run chmod command on utility to work properly.